# How to open download popup using Javascript/Jquery/Angular JS for the Excel Data return by Web Api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, asp.net-web-api

I have following web api code which returns data into excel file.

1. I have requirement to export (open download popup) for this data using
   **JavaScript/Angular JS/ Jquery.**
2. I want to add data into different excel sheets

*Note:* I do not want to create any copy of excel file at server, just wanted to show download popup to client.

Web Api Code Snippet as below -
1) Entity - Record

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace ExcelExport.Models
{
    public class Record
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

2) Controller - HomeController (URL - http://***ServerName:PortNumber***/Home/GetExcelData)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ExportToExcel.Models;
using System.Text;

namespace ExportToExcel.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetExcelData(int id = 0)
        {
            List<Record> obj = new List<Record>();
            obj = RecordInfo();
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.Append("<table border=`" + "1px" + "`b>");
            str.Append("<tr>");
            str.Append("<td><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=3>FName</font></b></td>");
            str.Append("<td><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=3>LName</font></b></td>");
            str.Append("<td><b><font face=Arial Narrow size=3>Address</font></b></td>");
            str.Append("</tr>");
            foreach (Record val in obj)
            {
                str.Append("<tr>");
                str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + val.FName.ToString() + "</font></td>");
                str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + val.LName.ToString() + "</font></td>");
                str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + val.Address.ToString() + "</font></td>");
                str.Append("</tr>");
            }
            str.Append("</table>");
            HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Information" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xls");
            this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToString());
            return File(temp, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        }

        public List<Record> RecordInfo()
        {
            List<Record> recordobj = new List<Record>();
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Smith", LName = "Singh", Address = "Knpur" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "John", LName = "Kumar", Address = "Lucknow" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Vikram", LName = "Kapoor", Address = "Delhi" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Tanya", LName = "Shrma", Address = "Banaras" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Malini", LName = "Ahuja", Address = "Gujrat" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Varun", LName = "Katiyar", Address = "Rajasthan" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Arun  ", LName = "Singh", Address = "Jaipur" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Ram", LName = "Kapoor", Address = "Panjab" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Vishakha", LName = "Singh", Address = "Banglor" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Tarun", LName = "Singh", Address = "Kannauj" });
            recordobj.Add(new Record { FName = "Mayank", LName = "Dubey", Address = "Farrukhabad" });
            return recordobj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: If you want to create sheets and more advanced functions outside of CSVs, you need to add a reference to the Excel Object Library dll. Then you use `new WorkSheet()` etc.